# What are the dimensions for a standard mug design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, dimensions

I am wanting to create a nice design in Photoshop and print it on a mug. The printing will be done by a printing company, but I am gonna need to provide the design.

The question is: What are the standard dimensions in pixels for a mug design? If I'm totally misinterpreting the requirements, then what would be the best way to create a mug design in Photoshop?

Comment: Welcome Aborted. There is no "standard" size mug. For design issues, please see the duplicate link above your question.

Comment: That link does not mention any sizes at all. I do not know at what sizes I should start designing my mug design...

Comment: As posted, there is **no** "standard" size. Cups/Mugs come in a million variations. You'll have to find the mug/cup you want to use at a print provider, then design for *their* mug.

Comment: You are totally misinterpreting the requirements. Pixels are a way to measure graphics on screen...not on a physical device. Plus, I don't believe there is such thing as a 'standard' size for coffee mugs. You need to get the requirements directly from the printer that will be printing the mugs for you.